# Product Type in Google Shopping API for Shopify

Tags: shopify, merchant-account

I can't find a product type in the google shopping API for Shopify

Products are appearing, all information is correct apart from where it says...

"Electric - Centrifugal"

[image]

I need to change the type to Electric Massicating. Other juicers on google shopping have this type however I can't see where in the type is set.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Google Taxonomy for Shopping](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160081?hl=en) and make sure Google has this product type. If they have it, it should either show up when using the [Google Shopping app by Shopify](https://apps.shopify.com/google-shopping/?ref=microapps) or if you use your own xml feed and send it to Google you should match that Google field with your [Shopify](https://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) product type.